# Power BI: Append similar table but null in custom column

Tags: powerbi

I have a table in Power BI which I'm working with. In this table I have some regular columns with values and I've created a custom column with a very simple formula. In this example the custom column is the result of A + B.

```
   Column A  Column B   Custom Column
0   20           5          25
1   30          10          40  
2   10          20          30
```

My problem is when in the Power Query Editor I try to append a new table with the same structure of columns of the main one but it appears null in the values of the custom column. This new table contains as well Column A and Column B but in the Custom it doesn't appear the result A + B but it appears 'Null'.

Is there any way of solve this? I mean, when I add a new table automatically it shows the values in custom columns instead of 'Null'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your issue correct, you are performing the "Add Custom Column" steps before you are appending both table. You can just change steps sequence between "Add Custom Column" and "Append Table".

First perform the "Append Table" step and then add the step "Add Custom Column". This will solve your issue.

Here is your case-

[image]

Here is after altering the steps-

[image]

Comment: Nice to see it helped and worked. you can also give an up vote to the answer :)